# I want to remove disable attribute from price (admin panel->catalog->products->edit product) in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, price

I have products with variations (size, heel size... etc.) Every product has the same price for all variations. I want to remove the disabled attribute from price(it is called "pret" in the picture below) input in every situation.

price input is disabled:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's installed using **`InstallData`**, you can remove it also with **`UpgradeData`**

Try like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

     $setup->startSetup();

     if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'your_attribute');
     }

     $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Or you can also delete it directly in your Magento database under **`eav_attribute`** table.